# Problema con sql (UPDATE) MySQL (Unknown column 'el texto escrito' in 'field list')

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo un problema y es que cuando se realiza un post desde un formulario me manda este error.

> (Unknown column 'el texto escrito' in 'field list')

El código que da error es este

```
 mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `nodes` SET `link1` = `$gen_link1` WHERE `id_ass` = '$id_user'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
 mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `nodes` SET `link2` = `$gen_link2` WHERE `id_ass` = '$id_user'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
 mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `nodes` SET `message1` = `$gen_message1` WHERE `id_ass` = '$id_user'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
 mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `nodes` SET `message2` = `$gen_message2` WHERE `id_ass` = '$id_user'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: En algún lugar estás pasando como nombre de columna, el texto que indica el error (`el texto escrito`).

Comment: Esta hay lo que estoy haciendo, pero nose, no le encuentro el fallo @Alfabravo

Comment: No es posible que ese error ocurra en el código que muestras ya que ahí todos los nombres de columna están escritos de forma explícita y además usando backticks. Revisa en que línea te dice que ocurre el error y comparte esa línea del código.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado el problema @A.Cedano :). >>>Abajo<<<

Comment: Ah ok, en los valores no debes usar backticks. Y, considera usar consultas preparadas, pues ese código es **altamente vulnerable** a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: No corrijas el código en la pregunta, debería quedar con el error, sino no se comprenderá la solución. Además puede servir para otros que les pase lo mismo. Los errores se corrigen en las respuestas.

Comment: No correji ningún error en la pregunta jaja, habia pueso otro error pero ya lo quite

Answer (score -1, accepted):

intenta con lo siguiente;

```
 mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `nodes` SET `message1` = '{$gen_message1}' WHERE `id_ass` = '$id_user'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Ahh, el problema esta en las '', tenia puestas estas ``, gracias jaja, ahora se setean en la base de datos pero da un error que no es mio. Inserto foto en la pregunta.

Comment: Ah, si es mio jajaja. Nada ignora. Muchas gracias

Comment: Ahora que pusiste tu nombre en griego se hace difícil mencionarte :) El problema es que usaba backticks en los valores y MySQL los consideraba identificadores (de columna en este caso).

Comment: lo comprendo pero si consideramos las reglas de [answer], creo que una edición y añadir esa explicación no cuesta mucho y ayudará a futuras referencias @A.Cedano

Comment: Claro, espero que Carlos mejore la respuesta, explicando cual era el error, es algo que le puede ocurrir a más de uno y una respuesta clara ayudaría a entender el motivo del error y a corregirlo.

Comment: mi +1 aguarda impaciente su edición :D @A.Cedano